# Как правильно оформить код для ввод текста на Python?

Tags: python, строки, файлы, чистый-код, pep8

Скрипт на Python в конце своей работы создает выходной документ output.txt
*Ниже приведенный абстрактный пример для понимания*

```xml
<!--vvv Начало шапки документа vvv-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com" xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com" elementFormDefault="qualified"  creator="Junior" version="0.00" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14 http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14/ABWInvoice.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:agrlib = "http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWSchemaLib/2011/11/14" xmlns:agr = "http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14">
<metadata>
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com"><text>Text for link</text></link>
<time>Date_time</time>
<name>Name_to_display</name>
<extensions>Red</extensions>
</metadata>
<!--^^^ Конец шапки документа ^^^-->
   <xs:element name="note">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
         <!--vvv Ниже, часть документа собираеммая скриптом vvv-->
            <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string"/>
            ...............
            <!--^^^ Конец работы скрипта ^^^-->
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

В этом документе есть определенный шаблон шапки (первой части документа), где необходимо вставить лишь два значения, а остальное остается по шаблону шапки.

```html
Значения для замены: <time>Date_time</time> и <name>Name_to_display</name>
```

Хочу узнать у вас как правильно оформить данную часть кода.

У меня на данный момент в голове только два варианта:

1. Полная запись всех строк в файл.

```py
with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as (file):
    file.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>\n')
    file.write('<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com" xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com" elementFormDefault="qualified"  creator="Junior" version="0.00" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14 http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14/ABWInvoice.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:agrlib = "http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWSchemaLib/2011/11/14" xmlns:agr = "http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14">')
    file.write('<metadata>\n<link href="https://www.w3schools.com"><text>Text for link</text></link>\n<time>' + str(Date_time) + '</time>\n<name>' + str(Name_to_display) + '</name>\n<extensions>Red</extensions>\n</metadata>\n')
    file.write('<xs:element name="note">\n<xs:complexType>\n<xs:sequence>\n')
    for j in range(len(trkpt)):
        file.write(trkpt[j] + '\n')
    file.write('</xs:sequence>\n</xs:complexType>\n</xs:element>\n</xs:schema>\n')
```

2. Иметь уже готовый фаблон head.txt.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com" xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com" elementFormDefault="qualified"  creator="Junior" version="0.00" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14 http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14/ABWInvoice.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:agrlib = "http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWSchemaLib/2011/11/14" xmlns:agr = "http://services.agresso.com/schema/ABWInvoice/2011/11/14">
<metadata>
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com"><text>Text for link</text></link>
<time>$metadata_time$</time>
<name>$metadata_name$</name>
<extensions>Red</extensions>
</metadata>
   <xs:element name="note">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
```

Его чтение и замена значений. И дальнейшая работа скрипта.

```py
head_file = open('head.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read().replace('$metadata_time$', str(Date_time)).replace('$metadata_name$', str(Name_to_display))

with open('obj/output/output.gpx', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as (file):
    file.write(head_file)
    for j in range(len(trkpt)):
        file.write(trkpt[j] + '\n')
    file.write('</xs:sequence>\n</xs:complexType>\n</xs:element>\n</xs:schema>\n')
```

Comment: как по мне, оба варианта имеют право на жизнь... работает - не трогайте ;)

Comment: Третий вариант: использовать шаблонизатор, например jinja2

Answer (score 3):

А что если использовать стандартное форматирование строк (что б в jinja не уходить). То есть в шаблоне $metadata_time$ и $metadata_name$ заменить на {metadata_time} и {metadata_name} соответственно
и

```py
data = dict(
    metadata_time=str(Date_time),
    metadata_name=str(Name_to_display)
)
head_file = open('head.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read().format(**data)
```

Comment: Хороший вариант реализации

Comment: Можно развить идею и на trkpt. Если я правильно понял? это список с неизвестным заранее количеством элементов. тогда в шаблоне можно вставить еще один элемент `{trkpt} \n`, а в data добавить `trkpt= '\n'.join(trkpt)`. Тогда в принципе все можно в один шаблон собрать и записывать уже отформатированный head_file.